# How to mock callback in jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

In jest test, I have a class. in its constructor, there is a function named `Center.setCallback`.
how could I do to expect the `this.accountSwited()` to be called?

```
import Center from 'xxxx';

export class LoginHandler implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        Center.setCallback((msg) => {
            if (msg.code === 10000 || msg.code === 10001) {
                this.accountSwitched();
            }
        });
    }
    accountSwitched() {
        console.log("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can mock your entire module  `xxx` then just simply cal in your mock as constructor gets called

Answer (score 0):

In file 'xxxx' (or Center.js file), from where you have imported Center class, you can do as below:

```
export class Center {
  constructor() { }
  
  static setCallback(callbackFn: Function) {
    /**
     * Do the task whatever needs to be done here and call the callbackFn in the last.
     */

    if (callbackFn instanceof Function)
        callbackFn();
  }
}
```